# AngularJS - Filter search for all true values

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have some data which generates an object of key value pairs in a nested fashion.

It will generate an object like such:

```
$scope.selectedVals = {
    shape: {
        oval: false,
        rectangle: true
    },
    size: {
        large: false,
        medium: true
    }
}
```

I would like to programatically use $filter to get only the values which are true. The result I'm looking for is:

```
var filtered = {
    shape: {
        rectangle: true
    },
    size: {
        medium: true
    }
}
```

I tried using $filter as such, but no luck, I just get back the original object:

```
var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.selectedVals, true);
                                 // the object        // the value to search
```

I know I could just iterate the object myself with a loop, but I'm looking for a way to use $filter if possible.

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/t3FhSvLgyXE8A3jfxWG0?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.selectedVals, {$: true});
```

Here's the angular documentation:

> Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on
>   objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"}
>   predicate will return an array of items which have property name
>   containing "M" and property phone containing "1". **A special property
>   name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any
>   property of the object or its nested object properties.** That's
>   equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described
>   above. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !.
>   For example {name: "!M"} predicate will return an array of items which
>   have property name not containing "M".
>
> Note that a named property will match properties on the same level
>   only, while the special $ property will match properties on the same
>   level or deeper. E.g. an array item like {name: {first: 'John', last:
>   'Doe'}} will not be matched by {name: 'John'}, but will be matched by
>   {$: 'John'}.

Comment: this solution does not work for me, have you tested this in the plunker? I updated it to show the output: http://plnkr.co/edit/t3FhSvLgyXE8A3jfxWG0?p=preview

Comment: their solution still applies for filtering objects inside an array. You cannot filter the attributes of a single object: you need to parse it as an array first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `$filter` on an Array and not an object.

Note that using $filter in your code only makes sense if you're writting a filtering directive. If all you need is "clean" your data then doing a regular pure-javascript is better and more performant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.onChange = function(){

    var arrayVals = Object.keys($scope.selectedVals).map(function (key) {return $scope.selectedVals[key]});
    console.log('original',arrayVals); 

    // I only want values which are true
    var filtered = $filter('filter')(arrayVals, {$:true});

    console.log('filtered', filtered);
  };
```

Basicallly get the values in an array then you can filter on `true`

Comment: This does not work, I tried it in the plunker and it still shows values which are false: http://plnkr.co/edit/lWLAibybv0K8EajMcGRw?p=preview